# Соединение (Connect) с БД (java JDBC DAO)

Tags: java, jdbc

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста с неисправностью программы, получаю `NullPointerException в строке preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);` подозреваю проблема в соединении, в методе `getConn`, но не уверен.

```
public class ProfileDAOImpl implements ProfileDAO {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        public Connection getConn() throws Exception{
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            try {
                properties.load(new FileInputStream("info.properties"));
                String user = properties.getProperty("user");
                String password = properties.getProperty("password");
                String dburl = properties.getProperty("dburl");
                String driver = properties.getProperty("driver");
                Class.forName(driver);
                if (connection == null) {
                    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(user, password, dburl);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return connection;
        }
        private PreparedStatement getPreparedStatement(String sql) throws DAOException{
            if(preparedStatement == null) {
                try {
                    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } return preparedStatement;
        }
        public void updateProfile(Profile profile) throws DAOException {
            String sql = "UPDATE profiles SET id=?, user_name=?," +
                    " nick_name=?, user_mail=?, password=?;";
            try {
                getPreparedStatement(sql);
                preparedStatement.setInt(1, profile.getId());
                preparedStatement.setString(2, profile.getUserName());
                preparedStatement.setString(3, profile.getNickName());
                preparedStatement.setString(4, profile.getUserMail());
                preparedStatement.setString(5, profile.getPassword());
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    public void closeConnection() {
        try {
            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

    public interface ProfileDAO {
    public void updateProfile(Profile profile) throws DAOException;
    public void closeConnection();
}

    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DAOException {
        ProfileDAO profileDAO = new ProfileDAOImpl();
        Profile profile = new Profile(2,"Test","Nick","test@test","123q");
        profileDAO.updateProfile(profile);
        profileDAO.closeConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Но ведь у вас в IDE есть дебаг? Почему не воспользуетесь им?

Comment: Конечно, у вас `Connection` будет `null`, ведь метод `getConn()` в котором происходит инициализация этого объекта, вы нигде не вызываете.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже отметили в комментариях вы не вызывайте метод `getConn()` - отсюда и `NullPointerException`.

Если у вас `connection` и `preparedStatement` всегда используются повторно, то лучше перенести их инициализацию в конструктор. Тогда `ProfileDAOImpl` получится такой:

```
public class ProfileDAOImpl implements ProfileDAO {
    final Connection connection;
    final PreparedStatement updateProfileStatement;

    public ProfileDAOImpl() throws Exception {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(new FileInputStream("info.properties"));
        String user = properties.getProperty("user");
        String password = properties.getProperty("password");
        String dburl = properties.getProperty("dburl");
        String driver = properties.getProperty("driver");
        Class.forName(driver);
        this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(user, password, dburl);
        this.updateProfileStatement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE profiles SET id=?, user_name=?," +
                " nick_name=?, user_mail=?, password=?");
    }

    public void updateProfile(Profile profile) throws DAOException {
        try {
            updateProfileStatement.setInt(1, profile.getId());
            updateProfileStatement.setString(2, profile.getUserName());
            updateProfileStatement.setString(3, profile.getNickName());
            updateProfileStatement.setString(4, profile.getUserMail());
            updateProfileStatement.setString(5, profile.getPassword());
            updateProfileStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void closeConnection() {
        try {
            if (updateProfileStatement != null) {
                updateProfileStatement.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: не задано поведение getConn так, чтобы выкидывать DAOE, как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: Если нужно выкидывать какое-то свое исключение то делается просто обертка, вот так: try { // тело метода } catch(Exception e) { throw new DAOException(e); }